# Move data with the same identifiers from rows to columns in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, opencart

I need to move data that have the same product_id from rows to columns.
Example:

```
From: table (product_image)
product_id    image  
----------    -----
12655         abc4.gif
12655         7hgd.gif
12655         8jd.gif
12656         23n.gif
12656         ej6.gif
12656         99j.gif
and so on
To: Table (sorted_image)
product _id    image_1    image_2    image_3
-----------    -------    -------    -------
12655          abc4.gif   7hgd.gif   8jd.gif
12656          23n.gif    ej6.gif    99j.gif
and so on
```

I have over 40,000 rows of data so I cannot address products_ids manually and one by one. Also it might be only 1 image for some and it might be up to 7 images for some other product_ids. The source table (product_image.image) does not have any other identifiers than product_id.

PLEASE NOTE, image names are all unique and there is no specific pattern for the name.

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Doesn't it look like to you that there's a better approach for this than creating a column for each image? Sorry I know that this comment is a little off of your question but it could also be a useful advice.

Comment: Dear @lucasnadalutti, I am open for any advice, but eventually they have to go in column because they will become part of a larger column and will be exported to other softwares who can only recognize it in columns labeled image_1, image_2 and so on

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Using the same ideas presented here:

[MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

The following is an approach that will yield a column populated with insert statements. These statements can be executed to create the table desired.  A couple caveats...

1. It assumes there is a set number of columns (7)
2. If you want to do this programmatically, it would need to be placed into a stored procedure that would execute each insert statement in a for loop or some other such construct

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_pivot
   ;

   DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product_test
   ;

   CREATE TABLE product_pivot (
     product_id INT,
     image1 VARCHAR(50),
     image2 VARCHAR(50),
     image3 VARCHAR(50),
     image4 VARCHAR(50),
     image5 VARCHAR(50),
     image6 VARCHAR(50),
     image7 VARCHAR(50)
   )
   ;

   CREATE TABLE product_test (product_id INT, image VARCHAR(50))
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12655, 'abc4.gif')
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12655, '7hgd.gif')
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12655, '8jd.gif')
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12656, 'ej6.gif')
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12656, '99j.gif')
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12656, '23n.gif')
   ;

   INSERT INTO product_test VALUES (12657, '23a.gif')
   ;

   SELECT
     CONCAT('INSERT INTO product_pivot ',
            c.col,
            ' VALUES ',
            v.dta)
   FROM
     (
       SELECT
         product_id
         , GROUP_CONCAT(col) col
       FROM
         (
           SELECT
             p.product_id
             , CONCAT('(product_id', ',',
                      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('image_', @sql := @sql + 1)),
                      ')') col
             , (
                 SELECT
                   @sql := 0) r
           FROM
             product_test p
           GROUP BY p.product_id) x
       GROUP BY product_id) c
     JOIN
     (
       SELECT
         product_id
         , GROUP_CONCAT(dta) dta
       FROM
         (
           SELECT
             p.product_id
             , CONCAT('(', p.product_id, ',',
                      GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('"', p.image, '"')), ')') dta
           FROM
             product_test p
           GROUP BY p.product_id) x
       GROUP BY product_id) v
       ON c.product_id = v.product_id
   ;

Comment: what do you mean by *"solved here"*? You know how Stack feels about "link only" answers. If not, you will. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144566/new-policy-on-link-only-answers then Google "link only answers stackoverflow"

Comment: by the way, that isn't my downvote and that's why someone else did that. So, now you know ;-)

Comment: Dear @Justin Gourley, I only have one table and also I need an statement to copy the data to another table not just selecting them

Comment: Fair enough.. I wasn't aware that linking to an existing SO post was deemed poor practice (i'm new).  It seemed more efficient given that it answers (what i meant by solved) the question posed. I'll post a more useful answer shortly.

Comment: @JustinGourley  the problem is image names are all different and there is no specific pattern for the name

Comment: @Schwann The sql inserts are simulating the table that you referenced above for illustration purposes. The select statement below all the inserts can be executed against your existing table and yield the desired results. It doesn't rely on any patterns, it simply takes the image name stored in the "image" column and places it into columns image_1, image_2, etc.  If there is only one image for a product id, it would go into image_1 and the rest would be null.  If there were 3 images, they would respectively go in image_1, image_2 and image_3 with the rest being null etc.

Comment: @Schwann Also you should be able to execute the code from above, as-is, in order to illustrate how it works.  From there just apply it to your actual schema and db objects either programatically in a stored proc or by executing the inserts in a .sql script.

Comment: @JustinGourley, thank you so much for the explanation, can it be modified to run it in mySQL instead of making a script? sorry I am not an expert.

Comment: @Schwann You can run it in MySQL as a script. Just modify the CONCAT to add semi-colons at the end of each insert.  Then save the results of the query into a .sql file. That's your script and can be executed with MySQL Workbench or using the command line or other tools.  That said, it would probably be more elegant to put the query in a stored procedure to automate the inserts.  That's a bit outside the scope of this question though I think.

Comment: @JustinGourley, Thank you, I was able to use MySQLWorkbench & make sql files with all the insert statements, there is only one issue, I am trying to upload that file with over 5000 insert statements like these ones INSERT INTO product_pivot (product_id,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4,image_5) VALUES (14910,'654.jpg','232.gif');
INSERT INTO product_pivot (product_id,image_1,image_2,image_3,image_4) VALUES (14911,'5678.jpg','87654.jpg','8765');
product_pivit are made with 7 columns, sql does not insert them and give me error that the column count does not match., is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: @Schwann the way the logic above works is that there should be exactly the same number of image_* fields as there are actual images for any given product_id. i would suggest examining your implementation to make sure it's doing that.  if you run the code above as-is, it produces inserts with the same number of columns as fields to insert.

Comment: @JustinGourley, I ran it the same way as I copied it above and as you mentioned wince the column counts already existed in product_pivit are different than the insert command's column counts. I was wondering if there is anything I can do to prevent this error that says, #1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1?